# Axes3D doesn't show plots

Tags: matplotlib

I am practicing Axes3D to play with 3D graph. When I ran code, I am able to produce the axis, but no plots in it.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df_test=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(0,1,(20,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter=(df_test['a'],df_test['b'],df_test['c'])
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('c')
plt.show()
```

Result is like below: As shown, there is no plots, only axis. What did I do wrong in my code? Many thanks!

Comment: It's my first post and I don't know how to attach picture, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The line `ax.scatter=(df_test['a'],df_test['b'],df_test['c'])` should be replaced with

`ax.scatter(df_test['a'],df_test['b'],df_test['c'])`, because you do not need the `=` operator.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df_test=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(0,1,(20,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df_test['a'],df_test['b'],df_test['c'])
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('c')
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't notice there is a '=' here.